# How to restrict postfix to only send to whitelisted recipients and to local aliases

Tags: postfix

Postfix is configured on a local network to deliver email via a relay host (Google authenticated smtp service).

I want to configure Postfix so that email is delivered only to either:

- an allowed recipient defined in a whitelist
- a local alias defined in `/etc/aliases` as long as they map to an allowed recipient.

So I have

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_recipients
    reject
```

and `/etc/postfix/allowed_recipients`:

```
MY_ALLOWED_RECIPIENT@gmail.com    OK
```

But this way when I try to send to root, it gets denied:

```
rcpt to: root
554 5.7.1 <root>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied
```

So, how to allow only whitelisted recipients **and** the aliases defined in `/etc/aliases` (without having to rewrite aliases in the whitelist too, I guess)

**EDIT**:

I found this configuration to work:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipients_allowed
    reject_unauth_destination
```

As per the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) the `reject_unauth_destination` option "reject the request unless one of the following is true:

- Postfix is a mail forwarder [snip]
- Postfix is the final destination [snip]"

and the last one includes aliases defined in `/etc/aliases`.

**So, I would ask if this configuration is the correct one indeed.**

Comment: @anx : thank you for suggestion, I tried it but it does not seem to work. Please not that I have `append_at_myorigin` enabled and I tried with both `@MY_DOMAIN_NAME OK` and `@MY_HOSTNAME OK` in the whitelist. Then I tried with a slightly different configuration in the main.conf and it worked, see my edit

Comment: And what content of /etc/postfix/recipients_allowed do you have now?

Comment: @gapsf the same as before, it contains only one allowed recipient on Gmail (which is the one root is aliased to)